# Verificar se existe valor de um elemento do array

Tags: php

Galera, montei o seguinte código para ler um `array`:

```
    for ($i_p = 1; $i_p < $array; $i_p++) {

        // Pega nome e valos da variavel
        $array_v_p = explode("=", $array_p[$i_p]);

        // Verifica se existe valor para montar variáveis
        if (empty($array_v_p[0]) !== (string) null) {

            if (empty($array_v_p[1]) !== (string) null) {
                $variavel = $array_v_p[1];
            } else {
                $variavel = null;
            }

            $$array_v_p[0] = "$array_v_p[1]";
        }
    }
```

É apresentado o seguinte erro:

> **PHP Notice:**  Undefined offset: 1 in index.php on line 8

Essa é a linha que está com o erro:

```
if (empty($array_v_p[1]) !== (string) null) {
```

Alguém sabe com tratar esse erro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Troque:

```
if (empty($array_v_p[1]) !== (string) null)
```

Por:

```
if ( isset($array_v_p[1]) and !empty($array_v_p[1]) )
```

Ou seja, se o elemento existe E se não está vazio.

Comment: ok vlw, deu certo aqui :)